# Send email when an application error occurs in Azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-diagnostics, azure-app-api

Use case is as soon as an error occurs in application, support team should receive a notification.

Looking for an out of box solution in Azure.

Current system configured for Diagnostic logs with below settings:

- Application Logging (Blob) - On
- Logging Level - Error
- Retention period - X days.

Comment: Maybe setup some kind of alert: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-alerts

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to your question?  I am interested in doing the exact same thing (notification on ever error)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, azure app service has Alerts feature. By using this feature, you could define which metrics will send the email.

About how to use it, you could refer to below images:

1.Find the alters in your from azure portal app service.

[image]

2.Click add alerts

[image]

3.Define alert rule

[image]

Comment: thanks for the explanation. In my case i want notification for every application error.